# pagination in teradata in ascending order

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to paginate sql query in teradata. Currently I have query as shown below:

```
 SELECT RANK(name) as rank_,id,name,address FROM tbl_users ORDER BY name
 QUALIFY rank_ BETWEEN 1 and 5
```

I want to achieve pagination in ascending order with column 'name' but this query fetches last five rows of the result set. 
For eg if the values of column 'name' is like 'a','b','c','d','e'......'v','w','x','y','z'

I was expecting values in the order 'a','b','c','d','e' but i am getting 'v','w','x','y','z'.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RANK(col)` is an old Teradata function, deprecated since more than 15 years. It defaults to descending sort, so `RANK(name ASC)` will return the expected result.

But the recommended syntax uses Standard SQL:

```
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name)
```

Comment: it works but the query execution time is much higher with rank function. any optimization suggestions.

Comment: @pradip: Did you check the actual QueryLog data? There should be no difference between old and new RANK.

Comment: actually ROW_NUMBER() worked for me since it generated unique values, but rank was returning repeated values

Comment: @pradip: Of course, RANK returns the same number for the same value. But ROW_NUMBER might return rows with repeated values in different order for each run. You need to add more columns until they're unique to avoid that.

Comment: i did not realize that. i am allowing users to order by several columns and some column values have same data and this will lead to a case where data row may appear in page 1 or page 2 depending upon my page limit. Is there a better way to simulate pagination like MySQL limit with offset. can we do something like SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name+increment function ) as rank_,id,name,address FROM tbl_users ORDER BY name+ increment function
 QUALIFY rank_ BETWEEN 1 and 5

Comment: @pradip: The only way is to add more columns to the ORDER BY. MySQL's LIMIT might show the same issue when ordered by a non-unique column.

Comment: To be clear, is "the recommended syntax" for RANK also deprecated? or just the old syntax?

Comment: @JohnVandivier: Of course, not. RANK OVER is the Standard SQL syntax every DVMS supports.